# What books comprise "Core" D&D3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I keep seeing references to "Core" D&D3.5e (as opposed to the SRD), but I'm not sure which books are included.  I know the Player's Handbook (PHB), Dungeon Master's Guide (DMG) and Monster Manual (MM) are  part of "Core", but what about the PHBII, DMG2, MM2&3, etc.?  Are they considered "Core"?

Answer (score 23):

If you look at the covers of the [Player's Handbook (I)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPATG.jpg), [Dungeon Master's Guide (I)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTZbL.jpg), and [Monster Manual (I)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ZEp.jpg), they say Core Rulebook I, II, and III, respectively. These are the Core rulebooks; everything else is supplemental.

Comment: Worth noting that a lot of people treat all of the [System Resource Document](http://www.d20srd.org/) as core, even though it includes material from the *Epic Level Handbook*, *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, *Deities and Demigods*, and *Unearthed Arcana* which are not actually a part of the original Core. d20srd.org helpfully does put all the Core-derived material under a column titled Core Rules, while putting the rest in a second column with their own headings.