# Are a Mystic's psionics (UA) affected by an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, unearthed-arcana, antimagic-field, mystic

*Unearthed Arcana* has taken up the concept of *Psionics* several times now. At first, with some basic rules for a *Mystic* class up to level 5 (which I can't seem to find online anymore, they seem to have been removed), then [an expansion up to level 10 for that class based on previous feedback](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/psionics-and-mystic-%E2%80%93-take-two), and finally [the complete *Mystic* class](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf).

The second version mentions:

> **Psionics and magic are two distinct forces. In general, an effect that affects a spell has no effect on a psionic effect**. There is one important exception to this rule. A psionic effect that reproduces a spell is treated as magic. [...]

However, the revised, third version states the following:

> As a student of psionics, you can master and use 
>   psionic talents and disciplines, the rules for 
>   which appear at the end of this document.
>   **Psionics is a special form of magic use, distinct 
>   from spellcasting.**

Now, *Psionics* count as a form of magic, it's just different from *Spellcasting* - but what **is** *Spellcasting*? Is it the class feature of e. g. *Wizards* or *Sorcerers*, which means a *Warlock's Pact Magic* does not fall into this category either? Or is it simply the ability to cast spells, which would include warlocks but (mostly) exclude *Mystics*?
For the sake of this question, let's assume the latter.

Later on in [version 3](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf), the section *Combining Psionic Effects* states:

> **Combining Psionic Effects**
>   [...]
>   Psionics and spells are separate effects, and therefore their benefits and drawbacks overlap. A psionic effect that reproduces a spell is an exception to this rule.

Therefore, the question remains:

---

**Would an *Antimagic Field* affect someone wielding psionic powers, such as a *Mystic*?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, a mystic's psionics would be suppressed by an antimagic field

*Antimagic field* says:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

So anything that is a spell or other type of magical effect will be suppressed.

The Sage Advice Compendium provides a handy checklist of questions to ask to determine if something is considered to be magical for the purposes of *antimagic field* and related effects. One of them says:

> - Does its description say it's magical?

If this answer to this question is yes, then that thing is considered magical and would be affected by the *antimagic field*.

#### Psionics is described as being magical

So, looking in version 3 of the Psionics UA we can find passages such as:

> Psionics is a special form of **magic use**, distinct from spellcasting.

and

> Psionic talents and disciplines are the heart of a mystic’s craft. They are the mental exercises and psionic formulae used to forge will into tangible, **magical effects**.

and

> Psionic disciplines are **magical** and function similarly to spells.

Thus, it is pretty clear that the use of psionics is indeed magical and would be affected by an *antimagic field*.

**Note:** spells and magic are commonly equated when, in fact, there are many magical abilities and effects that have absolutely nothing to do with spells. So, to be clear, psionic abilities are not spells even though they are magical and even though some of them act a lot like spells. Things like *dispel magic*, for example, will not work on psionic abilities as a result of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75475/discussion-between-seraphswrath-and-rubiksmoose).

Answer (score 4):

## RAW and most likely RAI: Yes, *Antimagic Field* will block *Psionics*.

This is the case because of the following essential sentence in [version 3 of the *Mystic*](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf). On page 5 it states:

> Psionic talents and disciplines are the heart of a mystic’s craft. They are the mental exercises and psionic formulae used to forge will into tangible, **magical effects**.

*Antimagic Field*:

> [...] Spells and **other magical effects**, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can’t protrude into it. [...]

Therefore, we can conclude that *Psionics* do not work inside an *Antimagic Field*.

**Please note that this interpretation might not be the RAI!**
It *being* RAI is supported by the fact that they removed the *"an effect that affects a spell has no effect on a psionic effect"* part.
However, the phrasing is still somewhat ambiguous and feels like the game designers want to count *Psionics* as magic for all intents and purposes (barring things like *Counterspell*, because *Psionics* ≠ *Spells*) - but they don't want to abandon the history of *Psionics* as well.

Currently, 5e *Psionics* aren't *spells*, but they're not the traditional *Psionics*, which draw from the *Far Realms* instead of the *weave*, either.

## Summary: *Psionics* = magic, but *Psionics* ≠ spells

---

#### Additional notes:

#### Historically (in the *Forgotten Realms*), *Psionics* would not be affected by an antimagic field, because [there used to be a distinction](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Psionics) between them and *weave* (↓) users. This is currently not the case anymore.

In the *PHB* on page 205, a sidebar explains the so-called *Weave of Magic*, which is a layer of sorts that (mostly) exists in the whole multiverse of the *Forgotten Realms*. Classic spell-casting classes such as *Wizards*, *Clerics* or *Warlocks* all draw upon this weave when casting spells.

This weave is clearly referenced in the description of *Antimagic Field*:

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. This area is divorced from the **magical energy that suffuses the multiverse.**

---

According to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/why-are-psionics-controversial) and [other online sources](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Psionics), psionic users do not draw their powers from the weave, but from themselves and their rare connection to the *Far Realms*. Therefore, their powers would *historically* (!) not be affected by effects like an *Antimagic Field*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105476/discussion-on-answer-by-pixelmaster-are-a-mystics-psionics-ua-affected-by-an).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know their 'magic' is from mind and originated from the Far Realm, and has nothing to do with the Weave. In fact, that is why even Ao couldn't do much about the [Spellplague](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Spellplague):

> Since the Spellplague was born from the defiling powers from the Far Realm, a plane that existed outside of Realmspace, not even Lord Ao had the power to stop it once it started.

And as far as I can remember, wizards and such utilize the Weave while performing spells, or when they dispel something - Even the anti-magic zone itself is described as a zone which the Weave doesn't exist in... So I doubt it would have any effect on a mystic from a lore perspective, as their powers drive from their minds rather than interacting with the Weave.